# Why is chromium-browser 63 so much bigger than 62?

Tags: package-management, chromium

I've noticed that `apt` estimates the upgrade to take **48.1MB** more space on upgrading from `62.0.3202.94-0ubuntu0.16.04.1317` to `63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`. I've skimmed through `apt changelog chromium-browser` and don't see anything that's described as taking much more space. Is there a quick way to see what files changed with `apt` or anyone who knows or will find the reason?

```
$ apt list --upgradable
chromium-browser/xenial-updates,xenial-security 63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 62.0.3202.94-0ubuntu0.16.04.1317]
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra/xenial-updates,xenial-security 63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 62.0.3202.94-0ubuntu0.16.04.1317]
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
The following packages will be upgraded:
chromium-browser chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 48.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Where does it show you that it'll take 48.1MB more space?  Are you sure you aren't seeing the "downloaded package installer" size for when it caches the package for reinstallation (so it doesn't have to redownload it in the future for a simple reinstall)?

Comment: It's `apt dist-upgrade` and the exact words are "After this operation, 48.1 MB of additional disk space will be used."

Comment: FWIW, the size difference is almost entirely due to a `v8_context_snapshot_generator` file (https://paste.ubuntu.com/26180050/).

Comment: Looks like this change https://codereview.chromium.org/2841443005/ , can you add it as an answer with a "Design doc" link included? @muru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size difference seems to be from a new `v8_context_snapshot_generator` binary file. I extracted the contents of the debs and compared them:

```
$ ls -sSh 6*/usr/lib/chromium-browser
61/usr/lib/chromium-browser:
total 222M
132M chromium-browser      5.0M libGLESv2.so                1.5M libVkLayer_unique_objects.so        1.1M chrome_200_percent.pak    220K natives_blob.bin       4.0K WidevineCdm            4.0K v8_build_config.json
 14M resources.pak     3.0M gn                  1.5M libVkLayer_swapchain.so         784K libVkLayer_threading.so   152K mus_app_resources_200.pak  4.0K angledata             0 libs
 13M ui.service        2.9M test_ime_driver.service         1.4M keyboard_resources.pak          772K chrome_100_percent.pak    128K views_mus_resources.pak    4.0K locales
9.8M icudtl.dat        2.6M libVkLayer_core_validation.so       1.2M brotli                  576K libwidevinecdmadapter.so   92K mus_app_resources_100.pak  4.0K plugins
9.0M headless_lib.pak      1.9M libVkLayer_parameter_validation.so  1.2M flatc                   508K libEGL.so          40K xdg-mime           4.0K swiftshader
6.7M font_service.service  1.6M libVkLayer_object_tracker.so        1.2M proto_zero_plugin           508K libwidevinecdm.so      36K xdg-settings           4.0K mus_app_resources_strings.pak
6.6M toolchain.ninja       1.5M snapshot_blob.bin           1.1M transport_security_state_generator  472K character_data_generator   16K chrome-sandbox         4.0K args.gn

63/usr/lib/chromium-browser:
total 270M
134M chromium-browser           3.0M test_ime_driver.service         1.2M snapshot_blob.bin           504K libEGL.so               44K chrome_100_percent.pak.info         4.0K WidevineCdm
 44M v8_context_snapshot_generator  2.7M libVkLayer_core_validation.so       1.2M brotli                  492K libwidevinecdm.so           44K chrome_200_percent.pak.info         4.0K angledata
 14M resources.pak          2.6M gn                  1.2M proto_zero_plugin           472K character_data_generator    40K xdg-mime                4.0K locales
 13M ui.service             1.9M libVkLayer_parameter_validation.so  1.2M flatc                   212K natives_blob.bin        36K views_mus_resources.pak.info        4.0K plugins
9.8M icudtl.dat             1.6M v8_context_snapshot.bin         1.1M transport_security_state_generator  188K headless_lib.pak.info       36K xdg-settings                4.0K swiftshader
9.1M headless_lib.pak           1.6M libVkLayer_object_tracker.so        1.1M chrome_200_percent.pak          156K resources.pak.info          16K chrome-sandbox              4.0K mus_app_resources_strings.pak
7.3M toolchain.ninja            1.5M libVkLayer_unique_objects.so        792K chrome_100_percent.pak          128K mus_app_resources_200.pak   12K mus_app_resources_strings.pak.info  4.0K args.gn
6.5M font_service.service       1.5M libVkLayer_swapchain.so         776K libVkLayer_threading.so         112K views_mus_resources.pak     12K mus_app_resources_100.pak.info      4.0K v8_build_config.json
5.3M libGLESv2.so           1.4M keyboard_resources.pak          576K libwidevinecdmadapter.so         72K mus_app_resources_100.pak   12K mus_app_resources_200.pak.info         0 libs

$ file 63/usr/lib/chromium-browser/v8_*
63/usr/lib/chromium-browser/v8_build_config.json:          ASCII text, with no line terminators
63/usr/lib/chromium-browser/v8_context_snapshot.bin:       data
63/usr/lib/chromium-browser/v8_context_snapshot_generator: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=99a63c90180ec5a32ea8861d44f405942ccbbdab, stripped
```

This seems to be a new tool meant to speed creation of V8 contexts. V8 is the JavaScript engine used by Chromium, and creating new V8 contexts is a significant part of the time taken for loading a webpage. The [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jpQQX0piaxcHJPWakp_Kr_03g5Gnma5h5-Kdlqu7jVQ/edit#heading=h.k6iklq6rvd30) suggests that creating contexts from V8 context snapshots should lead to a speedup of up to 3x, and this is meant to be a helper program for creating snapshots in the first place.

However, reading the design doc suggests including the tool in the package *might* be an accident, and hence a packaging bug:

> #### How to create a snapshot?
>
> A snapshot is created in build time.  It means a snapshot is user
>   independent.
>   We make an executable file which is run on host side platform to make
>   a snapshot. It simulates the behavior of
>   LocalWindowProxy::Initialize() to create a v8::Context, and outputs a
>   blob file as a result.

And:

> #### Concerns
>
> - This feature increases 1.6MB APK size on Android. It may be large enough to cancel the win.
>
>   - Android has no extensions
>   - This feature can increase disk I/O and memory usages.

The implication is that `v8_context_snapshot_generator` is to be run during package build time, and not on individual user systems. And the relative small size predicted increase for Android suggests that it doesn't include a 44 MB tool.

Comment: Good catch, and thanks to Mario for reporting this as a packaging bug: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1742653.